# Using phantom inside itemize

Tags: spacing, itemize, phantom

I'd like to use `\phantom{}` for spacing inside an `itemize` environment.
It however breaks a line.
What should I do?
The best solution I found was to replace `\phantom{}` by `\hspace{}` which is quite fastidious.

Example of code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a first item
        \item[~] \phantom{a first} atem
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The goal is to get the words item and atem perfectly aligned (which I find useful in beamer presentations).

Comment: You could place the item content in a *\mbox{}* including the *phantom* part.

Comment: It is not obvious to me why you want to put spaces inside an item. You should explain what you want to get instead of looking for the solution for the method that you are trying to get it. Moreover, a `\phantom{}` at the beginning of `\item` will not break the line (*as your example shows*) unless it contains a long sentence... so?

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I was indeed using an old TeX distribution

Comment: An alternative method could be ` \item a first \parbox[t]{4em}{item\\atem}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to the LaTeX release in December 2018, commands such as `\phantom` or `\thinspace` didn't initiate L-R mode (horizontal mode, in TeXspeak); now they do.

From your description, I deduce you're running an old TeX distribution. Update.

In the meantime, do `\mbox{\phantom{a first}}`.

What happens? When LaTeX processes `\item`, it goes into “between paragraphs mode” (vertical mode in TeXspeak) and only resumes L-R mode when something needs to be typeset (the main purpose of this is to allow `\label` without adding spurious spaces). However, with an old LaTeX kernel, `\phantom` would not trigger L-R mode, but rather form an empty (because of `\phantom`) line. Only `atem` would start L-R mode in your context.

With a newer LaTeX kernel the above simply doesn't happen.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Your edit was invalid, sorry.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry :).